# Sony Xperia Z : SocketTimeoutException Only Sony Xperia Z (4.4.2)

Tags: android, sockets, audio, sony, sony-xperia

### ***This problem happen Only Sony Xperia Z (4.4.2)***

I am working one android audio player app. the app read audio form sdcard as a local server.

I make local server because this audio are Encrypted and big size, so, if i try to run full audio file at a time and decrypt it then i take long time run media player that why i make this local server to read this audio file.

**My local server ServerSocket connection code.**

```
int SERVER_PORT=35415;
socket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT, 0, InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{127,0,0,1}));
socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
port = socket.getLocalPort();

Socket client = socket.accept(); /// this line give exception Only Sony Xperia Z (4.4.2).
```

**The problem is,** When i try check socket are open to read Audio Steam ([socket.accept()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29)) then it give `SocketTimeoutException` every time in Only Sony Xperia Z (4.4.2) not other android phone.

**What i have try to solve the problem:::**

1. Increase the socket.setSoTimeout(5000) upto 20000.
2. remove the socket.setSoTimeout(5000);  code to solve the problem.
3. Change the ServerSocket port form "123420" to "123440".

**Exception Log.**

```
08-18 20:18:54.344: E/AudioFileStreamProxy(8594): SocketTimeoutException
08-18 20:18:54.344: E/AudioFileStreamProxy(8594): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
08-18 20:18:54.344: E/AudioFileStreamProxy(8594):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:108)
08-18 20:18:54.344: E/AudioFileStreamProxy(8594):   at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:203)
08-18 20:18:54.344: E/AudioFileStreamProxy(8594):   at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:128)
08-18 20:18:54.344: E/AudioFileStreamProxy(8594):   at com.magnifo.utility.audio.AudioFileStreamProxy.run(AudioFileStreamProxy.java:98)
08-18 20:18:54.344: E/AudioFileStreamProxy(8594):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-18 20:18:54.344: E/AudioFileStreamProxy(8594): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: accept failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
08-18 20:18:54.344: E/AudioFileStreamProxy(8594):   at libcore.io.Posix.accept(Native Method)
08-18 20:18:54.344: E/AudioFileStreamProxy(8594):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:55)
08-18 20:18:54.344: E/AudioFileStreamProxy(8594):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:98)
```

Comment: I don't know about you, but [this `SocketServer` reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html) tells me that the first argument to the `ServerSocket` constructor should be an *integer* and not a string. And as it's a port number, it should be in the range of `0` to `65535` (inclusive).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg . I am edit my question, Please check it.

Comment: You listed 3 workarounds above to solve the problem.  What's the reason you can't use those as a solution?

Comment: I am try listed 3 workarounds above to solve the but the problem is not solve by this three 3 workarounds. It still gives SocketTimeoutException.